# Updating progress bar for AES encryption/decryption running on BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, aes, backgroundworker, filestream

I am trying to implement encryption for a desktop application. Since it could involve processing some large files (~2GB), I would also like to include a progress bar to show progress as the file is encrypted/decrypted. The function is being run on a background worker to avoid locking up the UI.

First I set up some vars for a buffer and a counter for the bytes that have been read, and how many to read next:

```
int ToRead;
long BRead = 0;
var buffer = new byte[1024];
```

The encryption function works in this order, READ -> COMPRESS -> ENCRYPT -> WRITE, but it first needs to write a byte array `EncryptionVars` containing everything needed for decryption(IV, salt, etc). The code looks like this:

```
using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        using (var transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
        using (var dest = new FileStream(destpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        using (var encrypt = new CryptoStream(dest, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var cmp = new DeflateStream(encrypt, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        using (var source = new FileStream(srcpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            dest.Write(encryptionVars, 0, encryptionVars.Length);
            while ((ToRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if (encryptionBGWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    encryptionBGWorker.CancelAsync();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    source.CopyTo(cmp, ToRead);

                    // Update the Progress bar
                    BRead += ToRead;
                    int progress = 100* (BRead/FileSize)
                    encryptionBGWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Decryption is similar but works in reverse, READ -> DECRYPT -> DECOMPRESS -> WRITE, but it also needs to skip the first X bytes as that contains `EncryptionVars`. The code looks like this:

```
using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        using (var transform = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        using (FileStream source = new FileStream(srcpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(source, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (DeflateStream dcmp = new DeflateStream(decrypt, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (FileStream dest = new FileStream(destpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            source.Seek(EncryptionVars.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);
            while ((ToRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if (encryptionBGWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    encryptionBGWorker.CancelAsync();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    dcmp.CopyTo(dest, ToRead);

                    // Update the Progress bar
                    BRead += ToRead;
                    int progress = 100* (BRead/FileSize)
                    encryptionBGWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The background worker code for ProgressChanged simply updates the value of the progress bar:

```
private void encryptionBGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (encryptionBGWorker.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string buttonName = (string)e.Argument;

        switch (buttonName)
        {
            case "Encryption":
                CreateEncryptedFile();
                break;
            case "Decryption":
                CreateDecryptedFile();
                break;
            case null:
                return;
        }

    }
}

private void encryptionBGWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    encryptionPBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void encryptionBGWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation stopped");
        encryptButton.Enabled = true;
        decryptButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        encryptButton.Enabled = true;
        decryptButton.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File processing is complete");
        encryptButton.Enabled = true;
        decryptButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The background worker is started on button click for Encrypt (Decrypt is the same with respective changes to encrypt/decrypt), with the following code:

```
private void encryptBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    encryptBtn.Enabled = false;
    if (!bgWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync("Encryption");
    }
}
```

Problems are 1: The progressbar is not updating on either function, 2: Decryption is failing with exception `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException` which is most likely due to `source.Seek(EncryptionVars.Length, SeekOrigin.Current);` not correctly seeking the position where the encrypted data begins, but I have not been able to find a solution.

How can I fix these issues, and is there a better/cleaner way to implement this code?

Comment: What UI technology are you using?

Comment: UI is being made in Win Forms .NET 4.6.1 @Liam

Comment: Well you lost me at [tag:winforms], but I'd say we'd need to see how and where `encryptionBGWorker_ProgressChanged` is called

Comment: ProgressChanged code was already in the post but I have edited to add the rest of the encryptionBGWorker code and the button click event which triggers it

Comment: why do you call `source.CopyTo(...)` it starts from the current position and also copies all remaining bytes. That's probaly why the progress does not get valid updates.

Comment: use `cmp.Write(buffer, 0, ToRead)` to write data to the `DeflateStream`

Comment: @Ackdari that seems to be working for the encryption side of things, the progress bar is working as it should, thank you for that. Any idea how to get the decryption working on the other side? Still have a padding error

Comment: You need to read from `dcmp` and write to `dest` using the write method